# tinyOS light (send packet if on else no)

Tags: tinyos

I am want to send packet if the light is on (on 500) not from (0) else not send. what I should to do ??

Please please help me on that

```
  event void Read.readDone(error_t result, uint16_t data) 
  {
    if (result != SUCCESS)
      {
    data = 0xffff;
    report_problem();
      }
    if (reading < NREADINGS) 
      local.readings[reading++] = data;
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [tinyOS (send packet if on else no)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284197/tinyos-send-packet-if-on-else-no)

Comment: I think I have to change on 0xffff